# How to sort array in Ascending Order in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a Site ID's Array at present it is displayed as 
112
110
109
108
107
105

But i want to display it in Ascending order please help
105
107
108
109
110
112

the typescript is like this

```
           item.siteIDs = [];
           (this.subscriptionData || []).forEach((subscription, key) => {
            subscription.sites.filter((obj: any) => {
              if (obj.addressId == item.entityId && !item.siteIDs.includes(obj.siteId)) {
                item.siteIDs.push(obj.siteId);
              }
            });
```

html like this

```
                      <td class="col-md-1">
                      <div *ngFor="let siteId of item.siteIDs">
                        {{ siteId }}
                      </div>
                    </td>
```

Comment: No sir, can you modify the typescript code i wrote and provide me a solution please

Comment: @SaiRam You can either build a pipe for that or just `sort` the array in your `ts` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a sort function like below and after you get the site id array , you can call this method on that array .

```
var siteIds= [112,110,109,108,107,105]
siteIds.sort((a,b) =>a-b);
```

In your code :

```
item.siteIDs = [];
           (this.subscriptionData || []).forEach((subscription, key) => {
            subscription.sites.filter((obj: any) => {
              if (obj.addressId == item.entityId && !item.siteIDs.includes(obj.siteId)) {
                item.siteIDs.push(obj.siteId);
              }
            });
item.siteIDs.sort((a,b) => a-b);
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined

Comment: Hi Haemandeep i got this error

Comment: It is type : it should be item.siteIDs instead of item.sideIDs .I updated the answer

Comment: Good to know that

Comment: Hi @Harmandeep singh can you help me to resolve this issue please   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65810945/angular-6-how-to-display-tool-tip-when-pointer-events-is-none-for-td