# Angular 6-How to display Tool tip when pointer events is none for <td>

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have a table inside td   which will be disabled based on ngClass condition but problem is tooltip has to be displayed even when pointer events are disabled with css wrriten on ngClass ,AT present tooltip is not being displayed because of pointer events none
but i want
Table td to be disabled  & at the same time tool tip also has to be displayed

```
**HTML:**

<td class="allowCursor" (mousedown)="!allowEventBaselineTwo(item) && selectRowExec($event,item,''+(pExec-1)+j);" data-toggle="tooltip"
             data-placement="top" [title]="tooltipHierarchy1(buildbaselineSpendType, item.business.id, item.country.id)"
              [ngClass]="{'noEvent':(bisinessStackholder == 'Y' && executeSaving == 'no' && projectStageNo >= ProjectStageCodeConst.EXECUTED)|| (projectStage == ProjectStageConst.IMPLEMENTED && isImplementedItem(item))|| ((item.businessStage==ProjectStageCodeConst.PENDING_APPROVAL || item.businessStage==ProjectStageCodeConst.AUTO_APPROVED || item.businessStage==ProjectStageCodeConst.APPROVED ) ||  (!rowEditable) || (item.isActive=='N')) }">{{buildbaselineSpendType === 'BF' ? item.business.name :item.country.name}}
                                                    </td>
```

CSS

```
.noEvent .allowCursor {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.noEvent{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```